# NeoEloquent Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$matches

Tags: php, laravel-5, neo4j, neoeloquent

I'm new to Neo4J and Laravel combined. I was trying out the Vinelab\NeoEloquent library to have a wrapper for Eloquent. Now if i try the default laravel auth code it gives me the following error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$matches.

I haven't changed anything but i was wondering if someone with experience could help me out? Do i need to change something? Registration works. It created the :User node fine. it also gives an error there: Call to a member function lastInsertId() on null.

Please note i use unedited Laravel authentication using the artisan make:auth function. As of writing this I'm using the latest version of Laravel (5.5) and the Vinelab\neoEloquent ^1.4.4 version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you still need/want the answer to this? I figured it out